# SpriteKit Scrolling Bottom Has Gap When Loops

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my app, I have an image that acts as the ground, and scrolls along the bottom.  I initialize and scroll it with:

```
 -(void)initalizingScrollingBackground
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bottom_Scroller"];
            bg.zPosition = BOTTOM_BACKGROUND_Z_POSITION;
            bottomScrollerHeight = bg.size.height;
            bg.position = CGPointMake((i * bg.size.width) + (bg.size.width * 0.5f) - 1, bg.size.height * 0.5f);
            bg.name = @"bg";
            bg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:bg.texture size:bg.texture.size];


            bg.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bottomBackgroundCategory;


            bg.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = flappyBirdCategory;


            bg.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;


            bg.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
            [self addChild:bg];
        }
    }

- (void)moveBottomScroller
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bg" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
     {
         SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
         CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-BG_VELOCITY, 0);
         CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(bgVelocity,_dt);
         bg.position = CGPointAdd(bg.position, amtToMove);

         //Checks if bg node is completely scrolled of the screen, if yes then put it at the end of the other node
         if (bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 0.5f <= 0)
         {
             bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.size.width*2 - (bg.size.width * 0.5f) - 2,
                                       bg.position.y);
         }
     }];
}
```

However, after it scrolls for so long, it shows a gap in it, as shown below.  How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Given that you are moving and checking for node going off screen in same loop,  what happens if first node is repositioned (because went offscreen) BEFORE the second node moves ? Using the debugger to step through and verify that locations are what you "expect" them to be, would reveal issue.

Comment: Agree with prototypical. Usually you update all backgrounds positions and then check for elements off screen. After you are not going to have more than one background off screen in the same loop. To be even more accurate you can also re-position the background using another bg's position instead of absolute position.

Comment: I'm learning SpriteKit right now so some of what you said is over my head, and this was simply from a tutorial, so I'm not sure where to go

Comment: @Willhem @prototypical everything about my code shows that it should be working great, but it still has gaps. `if (bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 0.5f <= 0)
         {
             bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.size.width*2 - (bg.size.width * 0.5f) - 2,
                                       bg.position.y);
         }`

Comment: @prototypical I am still stuck on this

Comment: I've tried changing values to see if it affects it any, and it doesn't, I've tried changing the size of the bottom scroller and it doesn't, the gap is always there, it just may start later for a longer image.

Comment: @Willhem said - "Usually you update all backgrounds positions and then check for elements off screen. " This would solve your problem likely. I asked a question, as I think it's helpful for you to think through the logic of my question.

Comment: And I said I'm very new to this @Willhem and didn't follow what you were saying.  Perhaps an explanation as to what that means and how I can do it?

Comment: Replying on the answer as I'm pasting code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is:

```
// This would go in the init or didMoveToView method of your scene
const NSUInteger numBgs = 3;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numBgs; i++) {
    CGFloat color = 0.2f * i;
    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:color green:color blue:color alpha:1.0] size:CGSizeMake(512, 300)];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0); 
    bg.position = CGPointMake((i * bg.size.width) + (bg.size.width * 0.5f), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame));
    bg.name = @"bg";
    [self addChild:bg];

    if (i == numBgs-1) { // Means it's last bg on the right
        lastBg = bg;
    }
}

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bg" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;

    //Checks if bg node is completely scrolled of the screen, if yes then put it at the end of the other node
    if (bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 0.5f <= 0)
    {
        bg.position = CGPointMake(lastBg.position.x + bg.frame.size.width,
                                  bg.position.y);
        lastBg = bg;
    }


    CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-BG_VELOCITY, 0);
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(bgVelocity,_dt);
    bg.position = CGPointAdd(bg.position, amtToMove);

}];
```

Where lastBg is an instance variable that points to the bg located at the top most right so that re-positioning is always going to be relative to this sprite.

Other things you can try are switching the check of the position before the re-positioning (as I did in the example) and also remove the check out of the enumerate block and do it independently of the re-positioning.

I used to do like in the example and it worked fine. Let me know how it does.

Comment: Thanks. As I said before just frustrating as I'm just now learning sprite kit and the tutorial was just like this so I do appreciate all help and am trying to learn and not just have someone give me answers.

Comment: Ok, where do I need to initially set the lastBg?  all I did was add an ivar for it, and the gap is now the width of the screen.

Comment: You should set lastBg when you setup the scene. Make sure lastBg ivar points to the last bg on the right when you do the setup. Also, positioning assumes all BGs have the same width.

Comment: Ok, so the current bg is setup like `SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bottom_Scroller"];
        bg.zPosition = BOTTOM_BACKGROUND_Z_POSITION;
        bottomScrollerHeight = bg.size.height;
        bg.position = CGPointMake((i * bg.size.width) + (bg.size.width * 0.5f) - 1, bg.size.height * 0.5f);
        bg.name = @"bg";`  How do I make sure it is set up to the right of that one?  Just make the x point `bg.size.width`?

Comment: I set it up like my last post described.  It was really weird, on the first loop, there was a huge gap, and then nothing at all, however, for some reason, it caused all my other nodes to be very low to the ground, like the bottom pipe on the flappy bird tutorial barely stuck out of the ground when I did that.

Comment: What you posted in the last comment is the same code you added on the initial description. Nothing has changed regarding the initial setup. I updated the code with the setup of BGs based on your code.